# SQL server linked server update

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

Currently working on a script which can update a number of different tables across linked servers.  I use 08/12 SQL server management studio.

I am having an issue where I have tried to set up the linked server string as a variable, so I can set this at the beginning and reference when needed through the script.  I have been working on the assumption I can declare this as a local variable, as I have for other parts of my script that are updating the local table/server, but when running the script, I receive an incorrect syntax error for the section of code my linked server string variable is located.

My code is structured as:

```
declare @string varchar(max)

set @string = '[server,instance].[database].dbo.table1'

update @string
set field = updatevariable
where record = identifier
```

Is it possible to use a linked server as a variable?

Comment: you have to use dynamic sql .. look it up

Comment: @SandPiper rude what? which part is rude to you bud?

Comment: Indeed @SandPiper. Please justify your statement. maSTAs's first comment was curt, but certainly was not rude.

Comment: This might be a better way to do it (Central Management Servers). I believe there are some more detailed explanations on SO somewhere too. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/execute-statements-against-multiple-servers-simultaneously

Comment: The "look it up" part. Not rude enough to flag, but it was uncalled for. You could have ended your comment right before that and not lost any meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically construct SQL Update string, and then pass it to `exec`. Example:

```
declare 
  @srv nvarchar(max) = N'[server].[db].[dbo].[table]',
  @id int = 100,
  @value nvarchar(max) = N'some value',
  @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql = N'update ' + @srv 
         + ' set field = ''' + @value + ''' '
         + ' where record = ' + cast(@id as nvarchar)

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I understand the basic construction on the code but could you explain the  inverted commas on this line of code: + ' set field = ''' + @value + ''' '.  I assume they have a function other then sectioning off text ?

Comment: @GrantSDC I don't understand what "inverted commas" you mean, but to see constructed `@sql` you can always `print @sql`